# Why did the smugglers assume that the video was provided by Frank Castle?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-punisher-2017

In Punisher, S1E2, after Carson Wolf "overwhelms" Frank Castle in his mansion, he states

> We thought you were the one that sent him the tape.

With *him* being *David Liebermann / Micro*. I've wondered why they assumed that Frank Castle made the tape, specially since on the tape, it could be seen how Frank killed *Ahmad Zubair*, which was visible on the tape:

> Madani: "Rawlins gave the order. Did Billy Russo pull the trigger?"
>
> Castle: "No, he did not. I did."

On Reddit, I've found [this explanation](https://www.reddit.com/r/Defenders/comments/7eb6f5/i_need_someone_to_help_me_understand_the_castle/):

> Rawlins realizes that someone inside the room sent the video (obviously) and assumes it was Frank because Frank took his eye. Gives the kill order to Schoonover.

Is that it? Rawlins just wanted to revenge and completely ignored the greater threat of having somebody leaking videos of their activities to the NSA?

Comment: I mean, it doesn't have to be "just revenge."  "Has problems with this enough to assault me" isn't too far a leap from "has problems with this enough to leak damaging video" especially if everyone else seems to be on-board.  Shortsighted not to consider other options, sure, but we see all the time shows with, say, cops centering on a suspect and ignoring contrary evidence because deep down they KNOW who did it.

Comment: It was not visible on the tape who pulled the trigger. Everyone present had masks on.

Comment: I think they might know who has the duty to kill a prisoner and it's not a _Well, who's turn is it today? Any volunteers?_.

Comment: It also didn't have to be visible to the viewer. 2 people in the room were available to double-check (Russo and Schoonover), and in-universe people on such a team should be able to recognise each other even when masked, even if they didn't already coordinate roles/positions. I think I have an answer to provide, but I'll want to get home from work and refresh my memory of this episode first.